# Why am I invited to edit a question I have closed as duplicate?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, post-notice

Here is the banner I am getting:

[image]

The link will open a new tab to edit the question. I don't think I need this.

Comment: Happens for non-duplicate closed questions too, and for ones I have had no involvement in closing.

Comment: ok so it seems a generic bug affecting the closure notice

Comment: This is likely an intentional (mis)feature. IMO, that button is worse than useless to 99.999% of people other than the OP. At an absolute minimum, before that button was added, they needed to address the issue of edits from anyone other than close-voters/flaggers pushing the question into the reopen queue. That button is very obviously encouraging people to make useless edits which usurp the OP's **one chance** at entry-by-edit into the reopen queue. How often is there an edit by a non-OP with rep < 3k which actually makes the question on-topic/non-dup? (rep >3k users can choose to reopenvote)

Comment: We *want* OPs to edit their questions into shape such that they can be reviewed and reopened. Making it *harder* for OPs to get their question reopened by encouraging them to be deprived of their *one* entry-by-edit into the reopen queue is counter-productive.

Answer (score 7):

I took away the edit/improve buttons for banners when the user has cast a close vote. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: First off, thank you for the work. Unfortunately, I think this question may not have communicated what I consider to be the primary point, although re-reading the question it's certainly about exactly what you changed, however that's not the real problem. For closed questions, we *absolutely* want edits from the OP which improve the question to the point of being able to be reopened. Those are great! The more of those we can get, the better!

Comment: The actual problems stem from the fact that the first edit that changes the body of the question puts the question in the reopen queue, as long as that edit is from someone that didn't vote to close or flag the question. So, we either want A) only body edits from the OP to automatically put the question in the reopen queue (best solution), or B) discourage, or at least not encourage, edits from anyone other than the OP or people who voted to close or flagged the question.

Comment: Edits from random people are largely *harmful*, because they 1) usurp the OP's single entry-by-edit into the reopen queue, depriving the OP of the opportunity to have their question reviewed, if and when they do improve it; and 2) make more work for reviewers in the Reopen Queue reviewing questions where the edit wasn't even attempting to make the question on-topic. #2 also conditions reviewers in the Reopen Queue to thinking that edited questions are 95%+ Leave Closed. This makes it more likely that a question that has been sufficiently improved will be erroneously reviewed as "Leave Closed".

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be a situation that should be adjusted on a site-by-site basis, as other sites may find that edits from non-OPs are able to make a question on-topic significantly more often than is the case here on SO.

Comment: @JWillborn What about people who flagged to close? Do they see it?

Comment: @10Rep I would assume that "cast a close vote" does not include "flagged to close" since those are two separate actions.