# Why do we need "Edit question" button while we have already another same one?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, post-notice

> [image: 1]

They have different styles but they redirect to the same page. So, why do we need both of them in the same post?

If the first one is used to catch the eye of viewers and recommend them to edit the post as much as they can, we should remove the second one.

But sorry, there aren't so much posts that viewers can edit to reopen them.

Comment: For the same reason the page has (at least) 4 jobs links

Comment: hopefully it helps the user to do the edit, without searching where it is

Comment: Maybe not a dupe, but very strongly related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398339/) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398340/)